# extra string being added to a text file during write() system call in C

Tags: c, operating-system

sorry this might be a stupid or trivial question. I have a code that I have written like this to write something to a text file.

I call fork() and have created a child.

My question is in my write() call, I didn't include any string "main" in the write() call, but somehow when I looked at the output, there are two lines that have the string "main" there like this:

[image]

and the following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("SomeFile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
    assert(fd > -1);
    

    // fork a child process
    int fChild = fork();
    if(fChild < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork is failing !\n");
        //exit(1);
    } else {
        sleep(7);
        int childNumb = write(fd, "A Message from Child!\n", 35);
    }
    
    int sec = write(fd, "Message From parent!\n", 29);
    close(fd);
}
```

I am not sure why the string "main" is being write to the text file. Could someone tells me what is going on?

thank you

Comment: You are writing more bytes than are in your strings.

Comment: @stark but may I know how the string "main" being output into the file? is it possible if you could elaborate little more? thanks a lot. Also when I have a call to close(fd), is it being called by both the parent and child process? but somehow child can still write to it after parent close it? or they both have their individual fd?

Comment: Parent and child each have an open file,  so both can call close independently.

Comment: @stark but does the string "main" there just get read from a memory to the file? so it could be something else instead of "main"? like it could be "apple", "orange" if it happens to be the case that at that time "apple" or "orange" appear in that part of the memory? so "main" was just a random coincidence?

Comment: Using bytes after the end of the string is undefined behavior. It may crash or it may pick up whatever data happens to be in that location.

Comment: @stark oh I see. tx for explanations.

Comment: @john_w do not use unrelated tags! How is your question related to ***"operating-system"***?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. What is 29? Why 29? How should anyone be able to verify that 29 is right? Do you propose that every reader of your program should count characters in a string literal manually? This isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the fork() doesn't fail, **both** processes write **both** messages.

As others have pointed out, you also overrun the end of the strings.  So first they write `"A Message from Child!\nMessage From"`, which is the child's message plus part of the parent's.  Then they write `"Message From parent!\n\0main\0\0\x01"`.  The word "main" is probably from the symbol table for your function, but could be from debugging information as well.

If you have a multiple CPU machine, you could also get these interleaved differently, probably both child messages then both parent messages.

I recommend code more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int writestring(int fd, char const *s)
{
    return write(fd, s, strlen(s));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("SomeFile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
    assert(fd > -1);
    

    // fork a child process
    int fChild = fork();
    if(fChild < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork is failing !\n");
        //exit(1);
    } else if (fChild == 0) {
        sleep(7);
        int childNumb = writestring(fd, "A Message from Child!\n");
    } else {
        int sec = writestring(fd, "Message From parent!\n");
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

You might also wish to include a `wait()` call in the main.

You might also consider the `open()` mode.  If you rerun this now, it just adds another pair of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this once. I am not sure it will work, but please reply to me when you try.

If the write function encounters a null terminator (\0) before writing the intended number of bytes, it might write additional data from memory, potentially including the string "main" if stored nearby.

Use `strlen` to determine the exact length of the string before writing:

```
int childNumb = write(fd, "A Message from Child!\n", strlen("A Message from Child!\n"));
int sec = write(fd, "Message From parent!\n", strlen("Message From parent!\n"));
```